# java deferred http client request handling

Tags: java, http, deferred

I've got a news server in Java and want to make it possible for clients to receive news as soon as they appear in database, without reloading client's page. For this purpose I decided to make HTTP request from client that returns response only after news become available. But if there are a lot of clients, server won't be able to accept new requests. So, is there any java technology that deals with it?

P.S. news server is just a similar model, but not an exactly problem, so, please, think about it more abstractedly=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [push communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). You could have a look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), or the [Java API for WebSockets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html).